# How to open a post through a slack link using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, slug

i am new in laravel working on a posting project, everything is working fine the post is displayed in a required way except that i want the user to view a post by clicking on a title which direct him/her to the post. As of now the post are being displayed in all details in a single page.

below is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class Kind extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    public function sluggable() {
       return ['slug'=>[
           'source'=>'title',
           'onUpdate'=>true
       ]];
    }
    protected $table = 'kinds';
    public function isOnline()
    {
        return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

My controller below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Kind;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class KindController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function display(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'organazation'=>'required',
            'country'=>'required',
            'title'=>'required',
            'message'=>'required',
            'requirement'=>'required',
            'deadline'=>'required',
            'reference' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255',],
            'financier'=>'required',
            'ownership'=>'required',
            'contact'=> 'required|numeric|min:6',
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'source'=>'required',
            'imogi'=>'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
           
        ]);

        $newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $request->imogi->extension();
        $request->imogi->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);


        $Kind = new Kind;
        
        $Kind->name = $request->input('name');
        $Kind->slug= Str::slug($request->name);
        $Kind->organazation = $request->input('organazation');
        $Kind->country = $request->input('country');
        $Kind->title = $request->input('title');
        $Kind->message = $request->input('message');
        $Kind->requirement = $request->input('requirement');
        $Kind->deadline = $request->input('deadline');
        $Kind->reference = $request->input('reference');
        $Kind->financier = $request->input('financier');
        $Kind->ownership = $request->input('ownership');
        $Kind->contact = $request->input('contact');
        $Kind->email = $request->input('email');
        $Kind->source = $request->input('source');
        $Kind->imogi = $newImageName;
        $Kind->save();

         /*
        return redirect()->back();
        */
        return back()->with('success', 'Send successfully.');

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Kind  $kind
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Kind $kind)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Kind  $kind
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Kind $kind)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Kind  $kind
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Kind $kind)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Kind  $kind
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Kind $kind)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In my view file

@extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-md-8">
       <div style="background-color:#162238; color:white;" class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
  <form class="form-inline" type="get" action="{{url('/search_tender')}}" role="search" method="get">
                    <input id="search-input" type="search" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Name,Organization,Location">  
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="submit" style="text-align: center; background-color:#131c2d; color:#3490dc;" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
                    <br/>
        @foreach($dataa as $dater)
        <div style="background-color:#162238; color:white;" class="card mb-3">
        <br/>
  <img id="nature" class="imogi" src="{{asset('images/' . $dater->imogi)}}"
        alt=""
        style="width: 80px; border-radius: 20%">
  <div class="card-body">
  <div style="text-align: right;">
  <i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-building-o" style="font-size:24px"></i> <small>{{$dater->organazation}}</small>  <small> <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ $dater->created_at->format('l, d F, Y') }}</small>
    </div>
    <br/>
              <!--LIVEWIRE online status-->
              @if($dater->isOnline())
              <small><div class="circle"></div></small> 
              @else
             <small><div  class="ocircle"></div></small> 
             @endif
              
    <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->name}}</h5>
    {{$dater->slug}}
    <small style="color:#3490dc;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i></small> <small style="color:#3490dc;"> posted {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dater->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</small><br/>
    <small><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->country}}</small>
    <hr color=3490dc>
    <h5 class="card-title"><b> {{$dater->title}}</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">
         {{$dater->message}}
        </p>
        <br/>
        <small><small style="color:#3490dc;"><b><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mandatory Requirements:</b> </small>{{$dater->requirement}}</small>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
        <small>Deadline: <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->deadline}}</small>
        <br/>
        
        <small>Reference No: <i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->reference}}</small>
        <br/>
       
        <small>Financier: <i class="fa fa-money" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->financier}}</small>
        <br/>
        
        <small>Purchaser Ownership: <i class="fa fa-user" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->ownership}}</small>
        <br/>
        <small>Office Contact Number: <i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->contact}}</small>
        <br/>
        <small>Email: <i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dater->email}}</small>
        <br/>
        <small><small style="color:#3490dc;"> </small> <a class="nav-link" href="{{$dater->source}}"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-globe" style="font-size:24px"></i> {{$dater->source}}</a></small>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
        @endforeach
        {{ $dataa->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

This is the view where i want to get rid of the dater and leave only a link(slug) to the full information, i am using laravel package cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable. I don`t get how to set it up correctly below is my web.php

```
Route::get('/tenderview', 'TenderViewController@index')->name('tenderview');
Route::get('tenderview', 'TenderViewController@show')->name('tenderview');
```

I will appreciate any help thank you in advance